# Honoring parents - before and after Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, parshanut-torah-comment, kibbud-av-veim-honoring, parashas-kedoshim

**In the Decalogue (Parashas Yisroh):**

- Keeping Shabbos is called Zachor (positive Mitzvah)
- It precedes Honoring parents
- Honoring is a positive Mitzvah (כבד).

**In Parashas [Kdoshim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.19.3?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&aliyot=0)** it says the "opposite" (אִישׁ אִמּוֹ וְאָבִיו תִּירָאוּ וְאֶת־שַׁבְּתֹתַי תִּשְׁמֹרוּ):

- Honoring precedes keeping Shabbos
- Keeping Shabbos is phrased תשמרו - (allegorically) as negative (refraining from doing forbidden actions)
- Honoring is also phrased תראו (allegorically) as negative (refraining from doing forbidden actions)

Does someone talk about this phenomenon in the Torah and its meaning?

Comment: The version in Kedoshim isn’t a negative commandment, but rather (generally speaking) a שב ואל תעשה. Two different things. Even so, one is obligated to stand up for his parents based on יראה not כבוד, so it’s not always שב ואל תעשה either. Good question nonetheless.